# IPv6 works on LAN, but doesn't work on WLAN

Tags: wireless-networking, router, lan, ipv6

I have the following setup:

- My ISP supports both IPv4 and IPv6 networking
- My modem is a Cisco EPC3208
- My router is a TP-Link Archer C2 (AC750)
- My laptop has an Intel Wireless-AC 8260 and is running Fedora 25. It is connected to the WiFi and does not obtain a WAN IPv6 address. It does obtain a local IPv6 address, however. When I connect the laptop to my router using a LAN cable it creates a new network interface and receives an IPv6 address and can ping6 ipv6.google.com.
- My phone is a Nexus 5, which can ping6 ipv6.google.com on WLAN. Therefore, the problem is with the setup on my laptop.

Here's the output of ifconfig on the laptop on WiFi:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 20086  bytes 1980721 (1.8 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 20086  bytes 1980721 (1.8 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:e5:31:7b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.113  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::de69:7bae:ac29:ff68  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fe80::ff78:cce:9e1a:8146  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fe80::84be:f382:5644:e16c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 34:f3:9a:26:40:b7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 135226  bytes 164427934 (156.8 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 49660  bytes 7543436 (7.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

and the output on LAN:

```
enp0s20f0u1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.114  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::ee1e:99a9:b350:5b9e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2a00:4802:a0e:9301:a490:bd15:2392:188b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 00:e0:4c:61:bc:03  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 132  bytes 34031 (33.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 364  bytes 34496 (33.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 17904  bytes 1743829 (1.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 17904  bytes 1743829 (1.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:e5:31:7b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.113  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::de69:7bae:ac29:ff68  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fe80::ff78:cce:9e1a:8146  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fe80::84be:f382:5644:e16c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 34:f3:9a:26:40:b7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 129833  bytes 159922423 (152.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 46548  bytes 6991129 (6.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I've toyed around with both the laptop's and the router's settings(including resetting everything) with no avail. Anybody have an idea how to fix this?

Edit: I can confirm that the same thing happens when I boot in as a Live user from a flash drive.

Comment: Sound interesting [Stable IPv6 address on Fedora](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331129/stable-ipv6-address-on-fedora) and this one too : [ipv6 bugs](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=982740)

Comment: @MichaelHampton It's a fresh install with the basic wifi config. I have no idea which config files are relevant, so I can post whatever you want. Here's a pastebin of the ifcfg of my connection: http://pastebin.com/CmzspAqu

Comment: I think it’s very strange for your WiFi interface to have three link-local addresses.

Comment: @DanielB Yeah, it is. But when I set IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE to eui64 in the ifcfg file (as suggested here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331129/stable-ipv6-address-on-fedora) I get only one link-local address...